# Sencha touch 2 - Save camera captured data into blob

Tags: sencha-touch-2

After clicking on save button I need to convert the file in to bytes and save it into sqlite database

Comment: are you using phonegap ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to keep in mind is a lot of the time these images are pretty large, so it is usually better to save the file location in the app instead of actually saving it into a blob, that will cause memory issues and the app to crash. There is a good post in the forum about using phonegap with the camera. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?119274-phonegap-camera

Also look at phonegaps documentation on taking images.http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera